# Viewing stats (such as critical chance) in Kingdoms of Amalur

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm enjoying my first play-through of Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning. I'm playing as a Rogue, and am getting pretty obsessive about my critical chance and critical damage (using gear, lorestones, and sustained effects).

Is there a way to view my damage statistics? I'm mainly concerned with critical chance and critical damage, but wouldn't mind seeing resistances (such as fire, ice, etc), and any others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Amalur doesn't have a hard stats screen. You'd have to look at everything that gives the bonuses individually (weapons, armor, destinies, twists of fate, abilities), and multiply them together. For example, two armors giving +10% and +15% critical hit damage individually would give +26.5% together. I assume that's how it would work, because you could easily become overpowered if the bonuses were added.

This method's kind of a pain, but there's no alternative.